# Fedora Widgets disappear on panel

Tags: fedora, kde, plasma5, panel, wxwidgets

I am running Fedora 30 with the following configuration:

OS: Fedora release 30 (Thirty) x86_64
Host: Latitude 5580
Kernel: 5.1.6-300.fc30.x86_64
Uptime: 23 mins
Packages: 3468 (rpm)
Shell: zsh 5.7.1
Resolution: 1920x1080
DE: KDE
WM: KWin
Theme: Breeze Dark [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2],
Icons: breeze-dark [KDE], Adwaita [GTK2],
Terminal: konsole
CPU: Intel i5-6440HQ (4) @ 3.500GHz
GPU: Intel HD Graphics 530
Memory: 3196MiB / 7594MiB

At first I installed two widgets: [binary clock](https://store.kde.org/p/1132273/) and comics strip to put on my panel but suddenly these two widgets disappear from my panel and from the widgets installer.

Is there a way from command line or with file system to install them again ? Maybe should I add a specific source repository ?

I tried with software center, look over the official package of fedora but nothing. I don't even know how to run these widgets (that I didn't uninstall from command line).

Comment: Not a common bug: https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Common_F30_bugs and a search of F30 bugs https://bugzilla.redhat.com/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=F30&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&product=Fedora&query_format=specific showed no mention of widgets, clock, or comics.

Comment: There is no KDE widget listed with the name 'Comic Strips'. Would you please look here https://store.kde.org/search/projectSearchText/comic+strips/page/1 and advise the name of the widget you installed, or provide the URL for the widget, then correct the original post with [edit]? Also, please try to reinstall with widgets following https://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Installing_Plasmoids

Comment: yeah I don't have the exact name for the comics widgets and I don't find it in the KDE store that's very strange. It was working good, I could choose comics such as : xkcd, cyanide and happiness, true or wrong ... and the widget fetch the daily strip for the selected comics

Comment: please try to reinstall Binary Clock widget following http://userbase.kde.org/Plasma/Installing_Plasmoids